# Why pointer to pointer of the same hierarchy are unrelated?

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, casting

Why does the following code produce `error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'Bar **' to 'Foo **'. Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast.`

```
struct Foo
{
};

struct Bar : Foo
{
};

int main()
{
    Bar **ppb = nullptr;
    Foo **ppf = ppb;
    return 0;
}
```

Aren't Foo and Bar related, so upcasting a pointer to pointer from one to another should work?

Comment: No, because otherwise you could do `*ppf = new SomethingElse` (where `SomethingElse` also derives from `Foo`).

Comment: OK thanks I get it, and thanks for the duplicate, I wasn't able to find the question on SO before :(. Sorry. You can close it.